# Confidence Interval for a sampling P95 in unknown distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size

**TLDR:** I need to estimate what is the minimum sample size to get a *W-wide* confidence interval of daily Response Time's P95 of which I only get a sample of events.

**Detailed:** Due to a Service Level Agreement, I'm trying to estimate the confidence interval for the 95th percentile of different services each day. Each one has *Mi* number of daily requests (large population), but I only get telemetry of some of the events (*Ni* randomly) which are my samples each day ( *Mi >> Ni* ).

Alternative, I could just get the sample size required to have *T* milliseconds range in my confidence interval around the sampled P95 and then use that as a threshold to be considered.

So far I was using Cox Method to estimate the CI of the mean, but observing the distribution of the sampled P95 values I get, it's right skewed and, as I understand, that invalidates Cox Method. (Not to mention, I'm not actually sure that Cox could be used to any parameter or just the mean)

On a different point of view, a colleague believes that given P95 is in fact determined by the top 5% of the samples, I could just use the standard confidence interval formula for unknown variance, but with *n = Ni/20*.

Any comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please define P95

Comment: Does P95 stand for the 95th percentile?

Comment: Yes, p95 is the 95th percentile. Edited the original to simplify